# PHP Startup: Timezone database is corrupt

Tags: linux, php, timezone

I have a CentOS 5.2 server. PHP is now at the 5.2.10 version (php-5.2.10-1.el5.remi.i386), and I have updated to 5.3, tzdata was updated too (tzdata-2009i-2.el5.noarch). Since the update, Apache refuse to start because PHP crash.

Here is the httpd/error.log

```
[Wed Jul 08 11:40:21 2009] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec) 
[Wed Jul 08 11:40:24 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ... 
[Wed Jul 08 11:40:24 2009] [notice] Digest: done PHP Strict Standards: PHP Startup: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected` 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in Unknown on line 0
**PHP Fatal error: PHP Startup: Timezone database is corrupt - this should never happen! in Unknown on line 0**
```

Best regards, Cédric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug opened on php.net: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48882

Here it is suggested to

> **add TZ=GMT in *(apache)* init.d script**.

It should fix the problem.

Comment: Great! I read this bug report but miss the "export TZ=GMT" in /etc/init.d/http script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but here is the answer anyway:  in the question, the asker is using the suExec mechanism.  those using mod_chroot or the apache2 built in ChrootDir will encounter similar problems.

make sure that {chroot}/etc/localtime and {chroot}/usr/share/zoneinfo exist - that's it.

credit goes to:
http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/alt-comp-lang-php/315265-timezone-database-corrupt.html#post1410153

Answer (score 0):

fixed it based on previous answer (CentOS v6):

```
nano /etc/init.d/httpd
```

but instead of UTC it's GMT+1:00. France may be GMT.

```
export TZ="Europe/Berlin"
```

and restart:

```
service httpd restart
```